# Laravel save user get routes for redirecting

Tags: session, redirect, laravel-5, routes

I have developed a system that rent flats, I have flat detail view, in this view we can rent, add cheque for specific flat, I just want to redirect to this page after add rent or cheque, for this purpose I want to save get routes that user click and redirect to second url, please help me to redirect to detail page after those works
I just want to use session to store routes and use them. 
Which one is the best way to save all user routes that pass in my system? In controller or middleware?

Comment: According to me the best way of saving route in session is from where you redirect so that there be only one and easy to know that it's particular one that required one.

Answer (score 0):

**middleware** is your answer 
as middileware is applied on a group of url and will save time to add in each controller function you can write a function in helper class and call in your middleware. 
Also, laravel itself has a method to get to previous url in case u need.

```
{{ redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl() }}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , can you please explain more?

Comment: to write less code you can write your function in middleware.